# Is that Future<>s pattern possible to do in dart(Flutter) as it is in JS?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I need to do something like this using dart's Futures(or else):

```
function Obj(){
  let resolver;

  this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolver = resolve;
  });


    //await firebase initialization or something
  setTimeout(() => {
      resolver('foo');
  }, 2000);
  
  return this;
}

var object = Obj();

(async () => {
  var result = await object.promise;
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Whats happening here, is I have an Object stored somewhere in a singleton(In JS example its an `object<Obj>` ) that is initialized somewhere at start, at the next line, there is another object initialized(In JS analogy its `async()` function). And this async function is waiting for `object<Obj>` to initialize its data like "foo" or else.

In JS, this setup is possible because Promises give you reference to `resolve`ing function that you can use anywhere. But looking at Dart's `Future`s I can't find anything similar, which is odd.

**TL;DR:**

**My goal is to have 1st object asyncronously initialize some data in its constructor and then somehow notify all other references to this object that data has been initialized.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is impossible to do that with Futures in dart as of now.
2. But: I was overcomplicating, just use global state controller for that. Whenever data is received, state gets updated, updated state is easily tracked in other objects that reference that state(Using streams generally).